# Google OAuth Accept button is disabled

Tags: google-drive-api, blackberry-10, google-oauth, blackberry-android

I have a Google Drive app running on BlackBerry 10 and PlayBook devices. The OAuth process was working fine for all users. Suddenly on Aug 23rd I received reports from some users complaining the "Accept" button is disabled and can't complete the authorization.
So far I noticed that these users use Spanish and Arabic locale (that's what appear so far from the screenshots and support emails they have sent). For the majority of the users, OAuth is working just fine.

One thing to note, my app is android app running using the BlackBerry Android runtime. When I tried the same code on android devices running android 2.3.3 and 4.0 the process is working just fine and the Accept button is enabled.

**On Sep 4th**, I retested on android browser on 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3 simulators, the Accept and Cancel buttons are both disabled.

Comment: We are looking into this issue.

Comment: @JasonHuang any update on this issue?

Comment: I retested on android browser on 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3 simulators, the Accept and Cancel buttons are both disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having same issue on android 2.3.3 android devices. It does not related to language.

[Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons are not enabled from Aug 22nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442171/google-oauth-login-page-cancel-and-accept-buttons-are-not-enabled-from-aug-2)

Google engineer replied to my question. It can be expected to be fixed by the end of this week.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the language because all of the reports are coming from non English people. I'm not sure why it's working for some and not the other.

Comment: As of now, its gets enabled if you sign-out and sign-in back from within the oauth dialog.

Comment: @JimJose Thanks for the info. It works that way but that still not the final solution I guess.

Comment: Seems like Google rolled out the fix... it is now working on both android and iOS in app browsers.