# Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons appear to be disabled

Tags: oauth, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I have a user reporting that when we send them through the Google OAuth process to connect with Google Analytics, they're encountering disabled 'Accept' and 'Cancel' buttons in their browser.

Screenshot (with permission from the user)

- Chrome: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzj30fht08pipab/google-chrome-oauth-issue-2013-11-27.jpg

This appears to be similar (if not related) to the issues reported here:

- [Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons are not enabled from Aug 22nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442171/google-oauth-login-page-cancel-and-accept-buttons-are-not-enabled-from-aug-2)
- [Google OAuth Accept button is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429638/google-oauth-accept-button-is-disabled)

However, the proposed fix by another user of logging out, then back in, within the OAuth dialog apparently did not work.

I have requested the user try a different browser in the meantime (still awaiting results), but I'm wondering if anyone else knows what might be up or how to fix this.

Addendum: Customer got it working in IE10, so the issue appears to be Chrome (or possibly webkit) specific. I was unable to replicate the issue myself.

Comment: I have seen the same problem over the last month or so in my apps.   I find if i just click on the screen a few times sudenly they are enabled again.   It seams to be random if it shows up or not.   My opinon is that its either a browser issue or an issue with the form that google gives us.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is that the JavaScript is disabled in the user's Chrome browser. for some security-related reason, Google OAuth 2 approval page needs JavaScript enabled on the browser. When the page is loaded, these buttons are disabled. They will be enabled by JavaScript in several hundred milliseconds (~500ms).

For DalmTo's case, I think he is not patient enough to wait for the 500ms delay, and thought his randomly clicks enabled the buttons, actually it is unrelated.

To me, it is unlikely that the OAuth 2 flow doesn't work on Chrome. Otherwise, you'll see lots of complaints here.