# OAuth disabled buttons

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I know that there are some similar topics here on stackoverflow. 
Like

[Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons appear to be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228819/google-oauth-login-page-cancel-and-accept-buttons-appear-to-be-disabled)

[Google OAuth login page 'cancel' and 'accept' buttons are not enabled from Aug 22nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442171/google-oauth-login-page-cancel-and-accept-buttons-are-not-enabled-from-aug-2)

But this problem was actual in August, and Google knew about it.
But I still face it in a few browsers on one system. And I'd like to find out about the status this issue is.

I have Win 8.1 system and the follow browsers have the problem:

1) Chrome - 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36

2) Ie 11 - 5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

The most interesting thing. that it works fine in the same system in Ie which has metro style.
Also it works fine in chrome on my windows 7 which has the same navigator.appVersion with the first one.

The error I get in console looks like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'p' of object [object Object] is not a function *******-aspen_approval_page_lib.js:16
I *****-aspen_approval_page_lib.js:16
(anonymous function)"
```

I checked my systems settings but nothing seems strange for me.
I debugged and the line when it fails looks like

```
I=function(a){return p(a)?document.getElementById(a):a},
```

But in my case p is just a string with the content "www2."
In script https://api.jollywallet.com/affiliate/client?app_id=tratataname=weDownload%20Manager%20Pro
I see code:

```
jw_md5.removeStart = function (url, l){ a = url;
    for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
p = l[i];
```

Before this call p is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"we download manager pro" is the problem. In ie it's a bho. In chrome it's an extension. This extensions adds to every page script from jollywallet and it breaks google oAuth script. And I'm afraid that a lot of users can face this problem....